# I have this issue where I run my program and I get a pop up saying Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013

I have tried for maybe more than a week and still stuck. I even searched around for solutions but still got nowhere. Can anyone help me? Also I am new to Stack Overflow. I posted what I thought would be reasonable to look at, and not the whole program.

My program is basically a Library management system. I can edit, add and delete books perfectly but not when it comes adding the customers from the user.

I have a struct `Customer`, I read from a file and transfer the data to an array of `Customer` objects. But in my `main`, when I call method `addCustomer` is when I see the Debug Assertion Failed!

It says :

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:\Windows\system 32\MSVCP120D.dll

File: c\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\xstring

Line: 1168
Expression: invalid null pointer.
```

My code:

```
struct Customer{

string first = "",
    last = "",
    id = "",
    phonenumber = "",
    email = "",
    BookID = "",
    return_date = "";
};
```

Adding the information to the array

```
void FileToArray(int& index, Customer library[]){
ifstream readCustomers;
readCustomers.open("CustomerDatabase.txt");

int i = 0;


// transfer file to array for customers

while (readCustomers >> library[i].id >> library[i].first >> library[i].last >> library[i].email
    >> library[i].phonenumber >> library[i].BookID >> library[i].return_date)

{
    i++;
}

index = i;

readCustomers.close();
}
```

Adding a customer

```
void addCustomer(int& index, Customer library[]){
/*
Adds customer to the database
*/

//Declarations
string firstName, lastName, email;

string phonenumber, NumBorrowed = 0;

// Get required input
cout << "First Name:" << endl;
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
getline(cin, firstName);

cout << "Last Name:" << endl;
getline(cin, lastName);

cout << "Email:" << endl;
getline(cin, email);

cout << "Phone Number:" << endl;
getline(cin, phonenumber);


// add to array for books
//LibraryCustomers[index].id = id;
library[index].first = firstName;
library[index].last = lastName;
library[index].email = email;
library[index].phonenumber = phonenumber;
library[index].BookID = "0";
library[index].return_date = "0";

index++;
}
```

main

```
int main(){

int CustomerAddCount = 0;   // Will keep track of the last index that has been added.
Customer LibraryCustomers[1024]; // Transfering the data from file to array 

FileToArray(CustomerAddCount,LibraryCustomers);
addCustomer(CustomerAddCount,LibraryCustomers);

return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't use the parameter you pass to `addCustomer`.  Get rid of all your global variables.

Comment: thanks  , I did that but its still seems kinda long... @Angew

Comment: @molbdnilo, I removed the global variables like you said, except the struct, and made sure I passed the variables and used them. The error is still popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problematic line:

```
string phonenumber, NumBorrowed = 0;
```

Look at the type of the variables: they're both `std::string` objects.

`std::string` has no constructor which would take an `int`. But it *does* have one taking a `const char*`. This means the `0` is interpreted as a null pointer constant, used to create a null `const char*`, and passed to the constructor of `std::string`. That [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) has a precondition that its argument points to a valid, nul-terminated string. That's not the case, so the program crashes (actually asserts).

Of course, stepping through your program in a debugger would have told you.